# Solving a system of 3 equations with 2 variables

Tags: linear-algebra

How would a system of 3 equations with 2 variables be solved to ensure that each variable is consistent throughout the system?

$$
a
\begin{bmatrix}
v1\\ 
v2\\ 
v3\\
\end{bmatrix}
+
b
\begin{bmatrix}
w1\\ 
w2\\ 
w3\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
c1\\ 
c2\\ 
c3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: What does "consistent throughout the system" mean? Also do you want *all* solutions  depending on values of $v_k,\ w_k,\ c_k$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rank of the coefficient matrix must be equal to the rank of the augmented matrix. In your example the matrix of the coefficients is $3\times 2$ so the rank is $2$, while
augmented matrix is $3\times 3$. To have the same rank the augmented mtrix determinant must be zero.